# append data with query result set

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to append the data with select query output

```
$project_code=DB::table('project')->where('customer_code',$customer_name)->whereRaw("owner in (select a.user_name from users a left join users b on a.manager=b.firstname where a.user_name='$user_name' or a.manager = '$first_name' or b.manager ='$first_name')")->pluck('name','code')->all();
```

result set `Array ( [IND_0068_02] => Test_Project_Dedicated1 )`
 I want the set as `Array ( [IND_0068_02] => Test_Project_Dedicated1 ,[0]=>no_client)`

From the above result set I want to add the value `no_client in name and 0 in code` in laravel 5.3.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description of what you have and what you want.

Comment: please add more description